# Meaning of negative value of MessageBoxA hWnd argument

Tags: windows, winapi, messagebox, hwnd

I'm analyzing a malware in IDA, where I observed the malware launching a MessageBox with negative value of hWnd (FFFFFFF7h). 
Message box arguments (Source:MSDN)

`int WINAPI MessageBox(
  _In_opt_  HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpText,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpCaption,
  _In_      UINT uType
);`

hWnd stands for owner window, I wasn't able to find what it means when hWnd argument is negative. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `hwnd` isn't signed, so you can't really say it's negative. I am not aware of this being a special `hwnd` value, maybe it's a previous error return blindly passed on, or maybe some window really has this handle. This isn't an assembly question, though, so I am retagging.

Comment: Best guess: a special value that different parts of the malware use to communicate with one another.  For example, installed malware might detect calls to MessageBox with that value and respond with a special signal.  That way, the malware installer can tell whether the machine is already infected or not.